# Omission of particles in haiku

Tags: grammar

This may be a little too specific, but am I allowed to omit particles with verbs in haiku? Here’s what I wrote for context:

> この世界
> から逃げるとき
> **夢入る**

Comment: A haiku needs a [kigo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kigo).

Comment: Ahh Ty imma try to put season words in them from now on, been doing it wrong for like a month now lmao

Answer (score 2, accepted):

に before verbs such as はいる, 出る and 行く can be omitted in colloquial conversation. Also in haiku, it can be omitted, but in this specific case, it would be better use [いる](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%85%A5%E3%82%8B), a literary version of はいる, and say 夢に入る【いる】.